# Fixed navigation bar for tablet and mobile issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, navigationbar

I am currently building a responsive website for a company and i came across a huge issue with my fixed navigation bar on tablets and mobiles.

**The issue is that while in both tablet and mobile the fixed navigation bar hides my content/jumps over them, when instead i want it to push the "contents" down while is toggle on.**

Also my .headerplace class hides the .bannerplace while on mobile. If you can help me this issue i will appreciate it guys.

Link to https://jsfiddle.net/wy38hy37/13/

```
<!Doctype html> 
  <title>NK Electrical LTD</title>
 <body>
<div class="container">
        <header class="headerplace">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="http://s15.postimg.org/q1sf0zvsb/nklogo.png" alt="NK Electrical LTD Logo">
            </div>
            <nav class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#electrical.html">Electrical Installations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#lighting.html">Lighting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#appliances.html">Home appliances</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about.html">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
            </nav>
            <a id="i-nav" href="#"></a>

        </header>
        <div class="bannerplace">

        </div>
        <div class="content-row group">
            <div class="primary-content col">
                <img class="headlineimg" src="http://s10.postimg.org/yvwknf09l/logoone.png"alt="Electrical logo"><h2>Electrical Installations</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>A house, a factory and generally every building has a life span of 40-50 years. The electrical installation for such a building will be designed and implemented only once, and should work reliably within time. The importance of the electrical installation process is of equal importance so as to be able to support the necessities of this amount of time within the years to come and not just of today. Therefore, due to this specific element, the electrical installation requires: experience, technical knowhow, excellent organizational structure and for sure an after sale service.</p>
                <p>In ΝΚ Electrical Ltd we have placed in action our past experiences, continuously trying to line up with technology reaching a high expectation limit in organizational behavior, but most of all we value the after sale service that mantles a serious part of the puzzle called electrical installations.</p>
                <button class="btn-action" type="submit">Book a table</button>
            </div>
            <div class="primary-content col">
                <img class="headlineimg" src="http://s29.postimg.org/4jne5no53/emergency.png"alt="Electrical logo"><h2>24/7 Emergency Service</h2>
                <hr>
                 <p>A house, a factory and generally every building has a life span of 40-50 years. The electrical installation for such a building will be designed and implemented only once, and should work reliably within time. The importance of the electrical installation process is of equal importance so as to be able to support the necessities of this amount of time within the years to come and not just of today. Therefore, due to this specific element, the electrical installation requires: experience, technical knowhow, excellent organizational structure and for sure an after sale service.</p>
                <p>In ΝΚ Electrical Ltd we have placed in action our past experiences, continuously trying to line up with technology reaching a high expectation limit in organizational behavior, but most of all we value the after sale service that mantles a serious part of the puzzle called electrical installations.</p>
                <button class="btn-action" type="submit">Book a table</button>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary-content col">
                <img class="headlineimg" src="http://s29.postimg.org/hp2wbri0n/lighting.png"alt="Electrical logo"><h2>Lighting</h2>
                <hr>
                 <p>A house, a factory and generally every building has a life span of 40-50 years. The electrical installation for such a building will be designed and implemented only once, and should work reliably within time. The importance of the electrical installation process is of equal importance so as to be able to support the necessities of this amount of time within the years to come and not just of today. Therefore, due to this specific element, the electrical installation requires: experience, technical knowhow, excellent organizational structure and for sure an after sale service.</p>
                <p>In ΝΚ Electrical Ltd we have placed in action our past experiences, continuously trying to line up with technology reaching a high expectation limit in organizational behavior, but most of all we value the after sale service that mantles a serious part of the puzzle called electrical installations.</p>
                <button class="btn-action" type="submit">Book a table</button>
            </div>
            <div class="third-content col">
                <img class="headlineimg" src="http://s15.postimg.org/8alw76z6z/homeappliances1.png"alt="Home Appliances 1"><h2>Home Appliances</h2>
                <hr>
                 <p>A house, a factory and generally every building has a life span of 40-50 years. The electrical installation for such a building will be designed and implemented only once, and should work reliably within time. The importance of the electrical installation process is of equal importance so as to be able to support the necessities of this amount of time within the years to come and not just of today. Therefore, due to this specific element, the electrical installation requires: experience, technical knowhow, excellent organizational structure and for sure an after sale service.</p>
                <p>In ΝΚ Electrical Ltd we have placed in action our past experiences, continuously trying to line up with technology reaching a high expectation limit in organizational behavior, but most of all we value the after sale service that mantles a serious part of the puzzle called electrical installations.</p>
                <button class="btn-action" type="submit">Book a table</button>
            </div>
            <div class="third-content col">
                <img class="headlineimg" src="http://s2.postimg.org/khlogvand/homeappliances2.png"alt="Home Appliances 2"><h2>Home Appliances</h2>
                <hr>
                 <p>A house, a factory and generally every building has a life span of 40-50 years. The electrical installation for such a building will be designed and implemented only once, and should work reliably within time. The importance of the electrical installation process is of equal importance so as to be able to support the necessities of this amount of time within the years to come and not just of today. Therefore, due to this specific element, the electrical installation requires: experience, technical knowhow, excellent organizational structure and for sure an after sale service.</p>
                <p>In ΝΚ Electrical Ltd we have placed in action our past experiences, continuously trying to line up with technology reaching a high expectation limit in organizational behavior, but most of all we value the after sale service that mantles a serious part of the puzzle called electrical installations.</p>
                <button class="btn-action" type="submit">Book a table</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="footerplace">
            <p>&copy;2016. NK Electrical LTD</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're header is stuck to the top of the page with position fixed & your nav is inside of this header, there is no way that toggling the nav will push the content of the page down.

This is because the current header has been "taken" out of the document flow, it does not affect any elements after it. The only way to have the navigation move the elements down the page is to remove the position fixed.

-- edit

On mobile breakpoint change the position fixed to position relative or inherit.

e.g.

```
.headerplace {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 100px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wy38hy37/15/ - now pushes the other elements on the page down.

Comment: Yeah, before i added position fixed everything was behaving appropriately, when i toggled my nav bar icon everything was pushed down but i want also my nav bar to move while the user scrolls

Comment: Yes with position fixed this isn't possible to achieve.

Comment: Any suggestion on how i can accomplish my goal without position fixed?

Comment: Yes thanks to your css corrections it pushes the content down on mobile but the user cannot see the navigation as long as it scrolls to the bottom so the issue still remains, but i appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue where my banner was hidden by my header/nav in the mobile resolution by adding padding:top:200px; on the body tag.

But still my main issue with my nav that does not push the content down is still there